# How to use rtmpdump for Android?

Tags: android, live, rtmp

How to work with rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu link is below:
http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/

For example I need to insert this command to it in Android project

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://199.9.255.241/app/jtv_dTmuAkM_lzohrwz2" -j "afbaf27e5a214e2eae89bcaf3da5a458d560ed4c:{\"swfDomains\": [\"justin.tv\", \"jtvx.com\", \"xarth.com\", \"twitchtv.com\", \"twitch.tv\", \"newjtv.com\", \"jtvnw.net\", \"wdtinc.com\", \"imapweather.com\", \"facebook.com\", \"starcrafting.com\"], \"streamName\": \"jtv_dTmuAkM_lzohrwz2\", \"expiration\": 1385721451, \"server\": \"video5-2.fra01\"}" --swfVfy "http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/widgets/live_embed_player.rd730d7268f3f46ec36fc591028917d9568f1fdf9.swf?channel=esltv_sc2&channel=esltv_sc2" -v -o out.flv
```

Comment: hi, did you manage to get it working ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille no

Comment: oh okie .. i was wanting to know hw to get it work :(. what was the workaround ?